# intellij idea scala formatting

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

What are proper code style rules in intellij idea for scala lang which after reformat (`Ctrl + Alt + l`) will result into *Desired formatting* ?

To format :

```
def withStatement[A](block: Statement => A): A =
  connection
    .createStatement()
    .withFinally(_.close())(block)
```

Desired formatting:

```
def withStatement[A](block: Statement => A): A =
  connection
  .createStatement()
  .withFinally(_.close())(block)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try reset value of the continuation indent to 0 for Scala code style as in following screenshot.

[image]